# Rails wildcard route with full URL in param

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to redirect to any given URL. I am trying this:

Route:

```
get 'track/*redirect_url', to: 'tracker#track'
```

Controller:

```
redirect_to params[:redirect_url]
```

However when I visit tracker URLs - I am getting strange redirects:

`http://localhost:3000/http://google.com/search=xyz` => `http:/google.com/search=xyz` (one slash is missing!)

`http://localhost:3000/http://google.com` => `http:/google` (slash + .com is missing"

Rails is apparently somehow transforming URL parts but since I do not have a control over it - I need a way to fix it.

Any ideas how?

Comment: I have a feeling that these are not valid urls. The embedded url likely needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because rails tries to parse that as a single url and fails because of escaping (// is parsed as "escaped /").

Also what happens to `.com` - it's parsed by rails as format (like .html or .json).

I would suggest you doing it with URL encoding and query-string params, eg:

`http://localhost:3000/track/?redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com`